# DocuSign API using XML to move Envelope to Recycle Bin

Tags: docusignapi

I'm having issues trying to move a completed envelope into the deleted bin in DocuSign using the REST API. The error I am getting is:

```
<errorDetails xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <errorCode>INVALID_REQUEST_BODY</errorCode>
    <message>The request body is missing or improperly formatted. &lt;envelopeMoveRequest xmlns=''&gt; was not expected.</message>
</errorDetails>
```

Here is the API call I make:

Address: https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountid}/folders/recyclebin 
 Http-Method: PUT

 Content-Type: application/xml

Headers: {Content-Type=[application/xml], Accept=[application/xml], X-DocuSign-Authentication=[{"Username":"username","Password":"password","IntegratorKey":"integrator key"}], Context-Length=[31274]}

 Payload:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<envelopeMoveRequest xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <envelopeIds xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:string>EnvelopeId</d2p1:string>
  </envelopeIds>
  <fromFolderId/>
</envelopeMoveRequest>
```

I could use some help figuring out how my API call is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following just worked for me. Make sure you are not copy/pasting any hidden or extra characters as well:

```
<envelopeMoveRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <envelopeIds xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:string>828a593e-10ae-4e54-bccc-66b5e66a5e81</d2p1:string>
  </envelopeIds>
</envelopeMoveRequest>
```

Comment: After some testing I figured out that having the XML Declaration:"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" was causing the error

Answer (score 0):

Usually the corresponding `XML` for DocuSign requests (when compared to the JSON equivalent) has extra nodes representing individual elements of a collection or array.  So in this case try adding an individual node for each envelopeId.

Right now you have:

```
<envelopeIds>EnvelopeId</envelopeIds>
```

Try changing to this:

```
<envelopeIds>
    <envelopeId>EnvelopeId</envelopeId>
</envelopeIds>
```